# Trying to create editable polygons with react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

Ive been trying to create a editable polygon with react-native-maps to basically create a user editable geofence. Using draggable markers to pinpoint the polygons corners. I thought this work, but upon dragging on of the markers, this error and I cannot understand why.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Polyline, Marker, Polygon } from 'react-native-maps';
import { RFValue } from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';

export default function App() {

    const [region, setRegion] = useState({
        latitude: 'null',
        longitude: 'null',
    });
    const [Cords, setCords] = useState('null')

    const [firstLat, setFirstLat] = useState()
    const [firstLong, setFirstLong] = useState()

    const [secondLat, setSecondLat] = useState()
    const [secondLong, setSecondLong] = useState()

    const [thirdLat, setThirdLat] = useState()
    const [thirdLong, setThirdLong] = useState()

    const [mapPressLat, setMapPressLat] = useState()
    const [mapPressLong, setMapPressLong] = useState()

    const polyList = [
        { latitude: firstLat, longitude: firstLong },
        { latitude: secondLat, longitude: secondLong },
        { latitude: thirdLat, longitude: thirdLong }
    ]

    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>

            <StatusBar style="auto" />

            <Text>{Cords}</Text>
            <Text>{mapPressLat} | {mapPressLong}</Text>
            <Text>{firstLat} | {firstLong}</Text>
            <Text>{secondLat} | {secondLong}</Text>
            <Text>{thirdLat} | {thirdLong}</Text>

            <MapView style={{ height: '40%', width: '90%' }}
                onRegionChangeComplete={(region) => setRegion(region)}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: 50.75895213387573,
                    longitude: -1.2904538133239536,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.01,
                }}
                onPress={e => setMapPressLat([e.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude]) + setMapPressLong([e.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude])}
            >
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'black', height: RFValue(5), width: RFValue(5), borderRadius: 100, position: 'absolute', top: '49%', left: '48.7%' }} />
                <Polyline
                    coordinates={polyList}
                    fillColor='#A3BE80'
                    strokeWidth={3}
                    tappable={true}
                    onPress={() => alert('yesy')}
                />

                <Marker
                    key={'first'}
                    onDrag={a => setFirstLat([a.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude]) + setFirstLong([a.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude])}
                    coordinate={{
                        latitude: 50.75895213387573 + 0.001,
                        longitude: -1.2904538133239536 + 0.001
                    }}
                    draggable={true}
                />
                <Marker
                    key={'sencond'}
                    onDrag={b => setSecondLat([b.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude]) + setSecondLong([b.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude])}
                    coordinate={{
                        latitude: 50.75895213387573 - 0.001,
                        longitude: -1.2904538133239536
                    }}
                    draggable={true}
                />
                <Marker
                    key={'third'}
                    onDrag={c => setThirdLat([c.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude]) + setThirdLong([c.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude])}
                    coordinate={{
                        latitude: 50.75895213387573 + 0.001,
                        longitude: -1.2904538133239536 - 0.001
                    }}
                    draggable={true}
                />

            </MapView>
            <Text>Current latitude:  {region.latitude}</Text>
            <Text>Current longitude:  {region.longitude}</Text>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCords([region.latitude] + '   ' + [region.longitude])} style={{ marginTop: 30, backgroundColor: 'darkcyan', borderRadius: 6 }}>
                <Text style={{ color: 'white', padding: 15 }} >Cords</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

[image: The error that happens when dragging the marker]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same issue as me.

I, for some stupid reason, put the marker's lat and long values in an array...

Old

```
onDrag={a => setFirstLat([a.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude]) + setFirstLong([a.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude])}
```

New

```
 onDrag={a => setFirstLat(a.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude) + setFirstLong(a.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude)}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Feel free to mark your answer as accepted. This will help anyone with the same error in the future.